# I am having trouble understanding what is wrong with my travis build

Tags: travis-ci

I am playing with travis-ci for the first time and have run into an error thats confusing me.

Below is my .travis.yml which validates when linted.

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 0.8

after_script:
  - echo "Hello World"
```

The following is my travis build output:

```
$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master git://github.com/iancrowther/travis-experiment.git iancrowther/travis-experiment
Cloning into 'iancrowther/travis-experiment'...
remote: Counting objects: 27, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
remote: Total 27 (delta 2), reused 20 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (27/27), done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), done.
$ cd iancrowther/travis-experiment
git.2
$ git checkout -qf xxx
$ nvm use 0.8
Now using node v0.8.22
$ node --version
v0.8.22
$ npm --version
1.2.14
$ make test
make: *** No rule to make target `test'.  Stop.
The command "make test" exited with 2.
after_script
$ echo "Hello World"
Hello World
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

How can i prevent the make file being executed?

Any help would be great, I cant seem to ind the errors explained in the doc's

Ian

ps. does anyone have any links to a guide about styling code??

**UPDATE**
when @User re-formatted the question, they added the following comment: "used {} button to make the code visible".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change `after_script` to `script`

Have a look at this `.travis.yml` :

```
before_install:
 - sudo apt-get update -qq
 - sudo apt-get install -qq python3.2 python2.7

python:
 - "2.7"

script: ./run_build.sh
```

The last line is the important one.

script is the command that runs the test.

before is something that enables the test to run
and after is something to clean up.
It is the same pattern you may know from unittests. Setup, Test, Teardown

Since Travis does not find a `script:` I guess it takes a default option for testing.

Comment: fantastic, this worked as stated.  The explanation is clear so many thanks @User